# UseState - Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

- I am using useState to update response from API.
- Then I am taking the data I need, and map them in a new array (arr)
- After the above step I am updating the "setData" useState hook to use "data" state
- But it is giving me Error
  **"Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called
  inside the body of a function component "**

> Here is the part of the code i am facing problem with

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios'
import ReactSearchBox from 'react-search-box'
import { set } from 'express/lib/application';

function App() {

 
  let [data, setData] = useState()
  
  useEffect(onMount,[])

  function onMount(){
      
      axios.get('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all').then(res=>{
        
        let arr = res.data.map((c)=>{
          return {key:c.name.common, value: c.name.common}
        })
        setData(arr)   
      })

     
  }
```

> My Full Page Code

```
import "./styles.css";
import axios from 'axios'
import ReactSearchBox from 'react-search-box'
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'

export default function App() {

  let [data, setData] = useState()
  
  useEffect(onMount,[])

  function onMount(){
      
      axios.get('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all').then(res=>{
        
        let arr = res.data.map((c)=>{
          return {key:c.name.common, value: c.name.common}
        })
        setData(arr)
      })

     
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Countries</h1>
      {data.length>0 ? <ReactSearchBox
        placeholder="Placeholder"
        value="Doe"
        data={data}
        callback={(record) => console.log(record)}
      />: null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

> Picture of Error

[image]

Comment: This isn't a solution, but don't use a function before it's defined. Even if you can technically do it. Also please may you share a [mcve]? I cannot replicate this issue with the code provided

Comment: when i remove the arr=res.data.map() ......   error does not come

Comment: this is a codebox link   https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-darkness-8rdzkh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The error is coming from ReactSearchBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`react-search-box`](https://github.com/ghoshnirmalya/react-search-box/) you're using [uses React 17](https://github.com/ghoshnirmalya/react-search-box/blob/master/package.json). This is not compatible with React 18. As a result, once your `data` state is populated and the `<ReactSearchBox` is invoked, an error is thrown.

Your code itself is fine - it's the dependency that's the problem.

Either:

- fork react-search-box and upgrade it to make it compatible with React 18, and use that version instead
- downgrade your React version to React 17
- come up with your own search box to remove the dependency on react-search-box
- wait for react-search-box's maintainers to update to React 18

Comment: A good alternative if you use material ui would be their [autocomplete component](https://v4.mui.com/components/autocomplete/#search-input)